# UITextView don't release with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting, uitextview

I have one more hypothetical question.

I create function:

```
-(IBAction)text:(id)sender{
    UITextView * textview = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

and because I use ARC I expected that object would be released when function goes out of scope .
But with Instrument I detected that memory is not freed.

Have anyone idea why?

Comment: I cannot get what you got from analyzer. The warning I've got is "Value stored to 'textView' during its initialization is never read".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARC will autorelease/release the textView wether it is nil or not

---

wrap it all in a @autoreleasepool to do so!

```
-(IBAction)text:(id)sender{
   @autoreleasepool {
        UITextView * textview = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
}
```

---

As for the **initial grow** when the textview is used the first time: the cocoa touch text system is allocated. (The underlying 'engine' that all textviews share)

Comment: As I sed I try that but if doesn't help. All other object that I try are released but UITextView is not.

Comment: you didn't say that.. with the pool? if the pool fails, you hold the textView somewhere else

Comment: There is no more code in the method. This is test method and it doesn't do anything. If I replace UITextView with UIButton or anything else it free memory fine.

Comment: the OP said the growth is worse if he opens the keyboard. SO here must be more code involved. how do you open the keyboard without even showing the textview?

Comment: Yes treu, if I add code to open and close keyboard it goes worse. But I was interested in this specific function without other code.

Comment: I tested it and can't reproduce at all it with only 4 lines :/ if you add it to a view or so, it is obviously held but for me -like this- it doesn't leak

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3753090/tester.zip :) this pushes and pops like crazy and alloc a view each time

Comment: I reproduce my problem from your code. You create IBAction but no button for it. If you delete your init function and add button to your xib file and connect it to IBAction. Open Instrument and watch memory.

Comment: AHHHH I think I get what you mean .. there is a _one time_ grow, yes!? The first time only, I edited my answer, sorry it took me so long

Comment: Aha I see. If you down vote  my question I would ask you to change your mind, and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -5):

Try this if you want to get it freed actually.

```
-(IBAction)text:(id)sender{
    UITextView * textview = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    textview = nil;
}
```

ARC only adds a release code automatically, it is not a garbage collector like other languages have. As soon as you give nil to an object it is released immediately. Else it is released when the "autoreleasepool" is flushed to which this object is added. (though im not sure on the last point.).

Comment: The textview will get released eventually either way, as no one is holding a strong reference to it. setting it to nil does not necessarily invoke any immediate action. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682128/when-do-these-objects-get-released-under-arc

Comment: so I should't care about this memory growth?

Comment: Marko you sure should -- if it a big growth and really doesnt go down -- wrap it all in a @autoreleasepool to make sure!

Comment: I get that Apple_iOS0304 is wrong, couse I test this before I ask question, but I want to know if I can get rid of it or when that memory will be freed?

Comment: yes, that's what I said, wrap it in an autoreleasepool. see my answer

Comment: Thanks Daij-Djan but I tried that. The growth is about 200 KB but if I open keyboard and close it it is about 550 KB